# How to Programmatically Create UITableView and Populate with NSArray in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2, storyboard

I have been struggling to understand the difference between Storyboards and coding in Objective-C. It appears you can create a UITableView by both dragging the object into your Storyboard, or coding in a new view within Objective-C.

The problem is that I want to keep my Storyboard as slim as possible. So I'm trying to build and populate a UITableView with an NSArray of 5 strings. My code will only run 1 row before returning a compiler error... I am going to scrap the whole project and start fresh.

I would be very grateful if somebody familiar with the new Xcode 4.2/iOS5/Storyboards can provide a reasonable solution for building the UITableView. I know this is such a basic task which is why it's so frustrating to begin with. I can get the Table View working, but I cannot seem to get an Array to dynamically fill and create #X number of rows...

Let me know if I can provide any more info. I've tried to be as straightforward as possible - just need to get a TableView working and populate with an Array :)

**EDIT** - here is my [project source code](http://cl.ly/D1ot) you can download to check out where I'm at.

Comment: Do you have sample code of your tableview class? It is alot easier to make it a subclass of UITableViewController. Pls include both the header and the implementation file.

Comment: @chourobin sure thing, just attached my xcode project source to my original post.

Comment: @JakeRocheleau - Just curious, why would you want your Storyboard to be as slim as possible?  I was under the impression that Storyboarding like interface builder allows you to have lighter code by doing things graphically and prevents future errors due to API changes.

Comment: @5StringRyan I think the app will compile faster, but mostly because I need to manage a recipe list of 40+. This can be organized and edited a lot easier in the code rather than all in Storyboard

Comment: I have a sample app with an NSMutableArray which populates a tableView but it doesn't use story boards.  Not sure if the story board part is key or whether you want me to paste my sample code ...

Comment: @bryanmac I would be willing to check it out for sure. Just need to get a working solution and I can pedal back to support iOS5/Storyboard

Comment: @JakeRocheleau - Well are you planning on having 40 tables?  I would assume that you would only need to create a few tables via storyboard, and then have the data dynamically populated on these tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it crashes is that in the storyboard you have to change the tableview to dynamic prototypes instead of static cells.
For some reason Static Cells is the default setting. Once you get the hang of the Storyboards it's great, especially when dealing with tableviews. Your initial View is set up as the NavigationController which has your MasterviewController as the RootViewController, so it's being loaded as the firstView. Click on the TableView in the MainStoryboard and change the Cels to Dynamic Prototypes or it will use the static ones that you create right in the storyboard. You can make custom cells right on the tableview in the storyboard. One more thing to note is the re-use identifier has to be set to the same name in the storyboard and the TableViewController. 
You can also just up the count of static cells to the number you want if you know it will always be the same.

Comment: For some reason Static Cells is the default setting. Once you get the hang of the Storyboards it's great, especially when dealing with tableviews.

Comment: man thank you so much! this problem has honestly been discouraging me for so long. I just couldn't figure it out for weeks and now I'm finally able to move forward with my project. Could you explain what the 're-use identifier' is and where I should set this value in the Storyboard?

Comment: Why the default is Static is beyond me. Most tableviews are Dynamic Prototypes.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a trivial sample with subclassing UITableViewController populated with an NSArray (NSMutableArray) from my sample code.  It doesn't use story boards but you said that's OK in your comment.  Hopefully my sample code helps you.

Header:

```
@interface MainTableViewController : UITableViewController 
{
    NSMutableArray *_items;
}

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation MainTableViewController

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Lifetime
#pragma mark -
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) 
    {
        // datastore
        _items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int index=0; index < 5; index++) 
        {
            [_items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"item #%d", index]];            
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_items release];
    [super dealloc];
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View DataSource
#pragma mark -
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // a typical table has one section
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // number of rows
    return [_items count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // NSIndexPath contains an array of indexes.  For UITableView:
    //    indexAtPosition:0 is the section number
    //    indexAtPosition:1 is the row number

    // create an identifier for this type of cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // get a cell of this type from the re-use queue or create one
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *title = [_items objectAtIndex:[indexPath indexAtPosition:1]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:title];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    return cell;
}


// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}


// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        NSLog(@"delete section: %d rol: %d", [indexPath indexAtPosition:0], [indexPath indexAtPosition:1]);
        [_items removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath indexAtPosition:1]];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) 
    {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        NSLog(@"insert section: %d rol: %d", [indexPath indexAtPosition:0], [indexPath indexAtPosition:1]);        
    }   
}

// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    NSString *fromItem = [_items objectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath indexAtPosition:1]];
    [_items removeObjectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath indexAtPosition:1]];
    [_items insertObject:fromItem atIndex:[toIndexPath indexAtPosition:1]];
}

// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate
#pragma mark -
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"selected section: %d rol: %d", [indexPath indexAtPosition:0], [indexPath indexAtPosition:1]);

    // get the selected cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    // navigate to detail
    DetailedTableViewController *detailedView = [[DetailedTableViewController alloc] init];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailedView animated:YES];
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle
#pragma mark -
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem: [self editButtonItem]];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```